# HTML Button onclick not working from the second click

Tags: javascript, html

I call a javascript function in my `button onclick`.

JS Code:

```
function getusername(){
    document.getElementById("strPwd").value="<?php echo get_user_name(); ?>";
}
```

Button Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="getusername()">Generate</button>
```

It works fine in the first run. But the problem is if I click again, it is not working. If I refresh the page it runs again.

What should I do ?

Comment: may be it works on second click, the value of '<?php echo get_user_name(); ?>' is same always, so not noticeable..? Btw, you didn't show getpassword() function …?

Comment: try jquery like $("idofbutton").click(function(){
    //your corresponding code
});  add id field to button

Comment: i think button click event already done a postback here, so no need of refreshing , just refer DemoUser's comment too

Comment: @DemoUser sorry......its my typing mistake. I changed my post.

Comment: @DemoUser it is not same always. I checked it in page view source. it is different in `JS function` but not working in `button onclick` so not displaying in `strPwd` `textbox`.

Comment: @Raj — It is the same until you run the PHP again, and PHP is server side code which runs when the page is loaded, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. I understood. I am trying to do it as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: @Quentin I would like to tell you that, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) is a process. But I need the way. Could you please give me a demo of ajax http request implementing my `php` code ?